# Group list by given occurrence in Scala

Tags: list, scala, unzip, sliding

I have a list of strings that I'm trying to split into separate lists sequentially, grouping the 4th occurrence i.e. this list:

```
val data = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
```

should be grouped as

```
val list1 = List("1", "5")
val list2 = List("2", "6")
val list3 = List("3", "7")
val list4 = List("4", "8")
```

I'm not sure if I am trying to overcomplicate this but the only way I can think is to first group the elements using `sliding` e.g.:

```
data.sliding(4,4).toList
```

results in

```
List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8))
```

and then to implement my own `unzip` method that would group the above as my desired output.

Please can someone let me know if there is an easier way of doing this?

Comment: It would be great if you could confirm the expected behaviour for lists longer than 8 elements....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.transpose` on the list `.sliding` generates:

```
scala> val data = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8") 
data: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

scala> data.sliding(4, 4).toList
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8))

scala> data.sliding(4, 4).toList.transpose
res2: List[List[String]] = List(List(1, 5), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

A version which will work for every list length:

```
def groupNth[A](n: Int, list: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  val (firstN, rest) = list.splitAt(n)
  val groupedRest = if (rest.nonEmpty) groupNth(n, rest) else Nil
  // null.asInstanceOf[A] is of course cheating, but the value is never used
  firstN.zipAll(groupedRest, null.asInstanceOf[A], Nil).map {
    case (h, t) => h :: t
  }
}


println(groupNth(4, Nil))
// List()
println(groupNth(4, List(1, 2, 3)))
// List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
println(groupNth(4, List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)))
// List(List(1, 5), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8))
println(groupNth(4, List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)))
// List(List(1, 5, 9), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8))
println(groupNth(4, List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)))
// List(List(1, 5, 9), List(2, 6, 10), List(3, 7, 11), List(4, 8, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` after `sliding`

```
scala> val data = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
data: List[String] = List("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")

scala> val result = data.sliding(4, 4).toList
result: List[List[String]] = List(List("1", "2", "3", "4"), List("5", "6", "7", "8"))

scala> result.transpose
res7: List[(String, String)] = List(("1", "5"), ("2", "6"), ("3", "7"), ("4", "8"))
```

Comment: This will work only if the list has exactly 8 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If tuples would do as output, it's fairly neat:

```
 val tuples = data zip data.drop(4)
 //> tuples  : List[(String, String)] = List((1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8))
```

turn them into `List`:

```
tuples.map{case(a,b) => List(a, b)} 
//> List[List[String]] = List(List(1, 5), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8))
```

EDIT: Showing that the comment about only  working with 8 is incorrect

```
 def pairs[A](xs:List[A], n:Int) =
 (xs zip xs.drop(n)).map{case(a,b) => List(a, b)}

pairs(List("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), 4)
// List(List(1, 5), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8))
pairs(List("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), 4)
// List(List(1, 5), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8), List(5, 9))

pairs(List("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), 4)
// List(List(1, 5), List(2, 6), List(3, 7), List(4, 8), List(5, 9), List(6, 10))
pairs(List("1","2", "3", "4"), 4)
// List()
pairs(List("1","2", "3"), 4)
// List()
```

Comment: This answer also requires `data` to have exactly 8 elements.

Comment: I have no idea why you say that, as it's simply not true.

Comment: If you have e.g. `data = (1 to 12).toList` you will return `List(List(1,5), List(2,6), List(3,7), List(4,8), List(5,9), ...)`; it isn't "splitting into separate lists" as in the question, because your results intersect. If `data = (1 to 4).toList`, you return an empty list.

Comment: It's not specified in the question what the behaviour is for lists longer than 8. Or less than 5. You have one intepretation, which I think is unlikely given how the OP has approached solving it `sliding(4,4)`. I think mine is more likely to be correct - we'll see what the OP says.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer agrees with mine for any length divisible by 4 (and throws an exception in other cases). It only agrees with yours for length 8.

Comment: Sure. Doesn't mean it's right, though. We have no examples for length !=8 from the OP, or approved by the OP.